# Hide Function in Google Apps Script Stops Working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet that tracks "open issues" for our departments. I have added a script where on open it hides rows based on the first character in column N being an "x". This allows us to only view open items. The script seems to have a mind of its own. It works, then it stops. Then it works again. Any insight on why this is occurring would be appreciated.

Script Below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Team 1 Unresolved");
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //get data from clumn N
  var data = sheet.getRange('N:N').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    if(data[i] == 'x'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet Link Below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N7va6hF14ecchCkrc8nMFGC-bVc1ZBlP7im7qhAKZAM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

I feel it had something to do with the first char. 
I would try to skip that part if possible.
this appears to be more accurate and working better...

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //get data from clumn N
  var data = sheet.getRange('N:N').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    if(data[i] == 'x'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks OblongMedulla! That seems to work. Any idea as to why it was getting hung up before? I can't imagine that it was too much data. Just odd that it would function "when it felt like it".

Comment: Not really sure- It seems it's about that first char part. But I am not sure as to why. But know, if it has xx or xyz or x - it will not archive them. It currently has to be an x and an x only .

Comment: So it seems to run fine initially. Then if I manually unhide the rows the script has issues after I refresh. If I manually run the script after that is seems to work fine again. So maybe unhiding breaks the on open command.

Comment: I am not sure if it would work for you but could add it to onEdit() or create a menu function to allow easy manually refreshing...